# Compare elements in dataframe columns for each row - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a really huge dataframe (thousends of rows), but let's assume it is like this:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  2  5  2  2  2  2
1  5  2  5  5  5  5
2  5  2  5  2  5  5
3  2  2  2  2  2  2
4  5  5  5  5  5  5
```

I need to see which value appears most frequently in a group of columns for each row. For instance, the value that appears most frequently in columns ABC and in columns DEF in each row, and put them in another column. In this example, my expected output is

```
ABC  DEF  
 2    2     
 5    5     
 5    5     
 2    2     
 5    5
```

How can I do it in Python??? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Have you checked out the mode function at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html ?

Comment: @MattVanEseltine but how can I make it row by row?

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way using columns `groupby`

```
mapperd={'A':'ABC','B':'ABC','C':'ABC','D':'DEF','E':'DEF','F':'DEF'}
df.groupby(mapperd,axis=1).agg(lambda x : x.mode()[0])
Out[826]: 
   ABC  DEF
0    2    2
1    5    5
2    5    5
3    2    2
4    5    5
```

Answer (score 4):

For a good performance you can work with the underlying numpy arrays, and use [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) to compute the **mode**:

```
from scipy import stats
cols = ['ABC','DEF']
a = df.values.reshape(-1, df.shape[1]//2)
pd.DataFrame(stats.mode(a, axis=1).mode.reshape(-1,2), columns=cols)

    ABC  DEF
0    2    2
1    5    5
2    5    5
3    2    2
4    5    5
```

Answer (score 3):

You try using column header index filtering:

```
grp = ['ABC','DEF']
pd.concat([df.loc[:,[*g]].mode(1).set_axis([g], axis=1, inplace=False) for g in grp], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ABC  DEF
0    2    2
1    5    5
2    5    5
3    2    2
4    5    5
```